# MySQL how to append strings to external files on disk?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, logging

Using MySQL with stored procedures, I want to be enable to append messages to a file on disk from a stored procedure.

Is there any tool or framework for logging messages to disk in stored procedures?

Ok so it isn't possible to write directly to disk, is there any work-around hacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to append text to files on disk in MySQL. Stored procedures cannot write arbitrary text into a file on the file system (virtually no SQL statement can, for that matter).

**However,** your stored procedure could insert rows into a table, used for logging purposes only.  You could then use [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) on the commandline to read from and dump the contents of the log table into a text file.  Or with a well crafted [`SELECT...INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html)) query.

Comment: can't you then also let the procedure `select "something" as log into outfile"`?

Comment: OMG yes indeed you can :D Dirty, but obvious, it must have triggered some kind of fail safe in my mind. I don't think one can append to an existing file, though.